# PHP Add Space Every 4th Character but ignore when you reach a comma

Tags: php

This is my line

```
AQUA19097444,AQUA43188766,AQUA49556282,AQUA51389151,AQUA57267110,BLUE12811521,BLUE15966728
```

This is what I **want to achieve in the end**

```
AQUA 1909 7444,AQUA 4318 8766,AQUA 4955 6282,AQUA 5138 9151,AQUA 5726 7110,BLUE 1281 1521,BLUE 1596 6728
```

Notice there is space every 4 characters but does not include a space if a comma is next.

This is what I have tried so far: note I am in a for each loop

```
$Raffles[$index] = chunk_split($Raffles[$index], 4, ' ');
```

This is the output of the code

```
AQUA 1909 7444 ,AQU A431 8876 6,AQ UA49 5562 82,A QUA5 1389 151, AQUA 5726 7110 ,BLU E128 1152 1,BL UE15 9667 28
```

As you can see it does a space when It reaches the comma which I want it to ignore

Please help me out and thank you for reading my question.

Comment: explode on comma, loop over and chunk_split each value, join back on comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode your string, then loop through it and use `chunk_split` to place the space every fourth character.

```
$string = 'AQUA19097444,AQUA43188766,AQUA49556282,AQUA51389151,AQUA57267110,BLUE12811521,BLUE15966728';

$exploded_string = explode(',', $string);

foreach($exploded_string as $item){
    $result[] = chunk_split($item, 4, ' ');
}
```

`print_r($result);` will give you

```
Array ( [0] => AQUA 1909 7444 
        [1] => AQUA 4318 8766 
        [2] => AQUA 4955 6282 
        [3] => AQUA 5138 9151 
        [4] => AQUA 5726 7110 
        [5] => BLUE 1281 1521 
        [6] => BLUE 1596 6728 )
```

If you want to convert this back into a comma separated string use `$result = implode(',', $result);`

Answer (score 4):

The complex way:

```
$Raffles[$index] = implode(",",array_map(function($p) {return chunk_split($p,4," ");},explode(",",$Raffles[$index])));
```

(Note that you can potentially do that without being in a `foreach` loop by wrapping another `array_map` around it)

The black magic way:

```
$Raffles[$index] = preg_replace("/([^,]{4})(?!,)(?=.)/","$1 ",$Raffles[$index]);
```

Comment: Not enough tail of newt?

Answer (score -1):

Something like the below should work...

```
    $string ='AQUA19097444,AQUA43188766,AQUA49556282,AQUA51389151,AQUA57267110,BLUE12811521,BLUE15966728';
    $explode = explode(',',$string);

    $count = 0;

    while (!empty($explode[$count])) {
        $var[] = chunk_split($explode[$count], 4, ' ');
        $count++;
    }
```

Comment: Change `$var` to `$var[]` to create the array.

Comment: while this does work, that is quite an odd way to loop over an array. Especially when there are much easier and safer options like a foreach. Especially if you consider that there might be the possibility that one of the resulting values could have a value that evaluates to empty but is perfectly valid. Just a critique to help.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan. Try and offer answers that use the most standard and safe options, it helps new coders write better code.